# Nextjs - changing menu urls based on active language

Tags: next.js

So, I want to change the menu items on a page depending on what language that currently is active. I have managed to add a language selector by using i18n.
What I want to achieve is to update the menu items on the specific pages based on what language that is active.

So, if English (default language) the menu item would just be /introduction whereas if French is active it would be /introduction/fr.

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fr'],
    defaultLocale: 'en'
  }
}
```

**_app.jsx**

```
var router = useRouter ()
const { locale } = useRouter();

const menu = [
    {
      title: 'Introduction',
      links: [
        { title: 'Introduction', href: '/introduction/${locale}' },
      ],
    },
  ]
```

Any guidance in what I am missing out on would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What's not working with your current approach? Can you show us the code you have for the menu items UI?

Answer (score 0):

We include english and french as locales

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en-US", "fr-FR"],
    defaultLocale: "en-US"
  }
};
```

We iterate over menu array and generate our next links dynamically. You should tweak the code if you will have multiple nested links, this is just a quick start.

```
function App() {
  const { locale } = useRouter();

  const menu = [
    {
      title: 'Introduction',
      links: [
        { title: 'Introduction', href: '/introduction/${locale}' },
      ],
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <div className={styles.navbar}>
          {menu.map((m, i) => {
            return (
              <span key={i}>
                <Link href={m.links ? m.links[0].href : '#'}>
                  {m.title}
                </Link>
              </span>
            ); 
          })}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS

```
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  width: 65%;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.navbar span {
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Further reading

[Multi-Language Website with NextJs](https://www.datocms.com/blog/how-to-build-a-multi-language-website-with-next-js-i18n)